# Iterating through children of a layer in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to iterate through and remove all children of my layer (HUDLayer).  I am trying to accomplish this task with:

```
    for(id *item in HUDLayer.children_)
    {
        [self removeChild:item cleanup:YES];
    }
```

But I get an error -> Expression does not have a valid object type

Can someone shed some light on my issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(id *item
```

Whoops. `id` is an object itself (and a pointer too), no need for the asterisk.

```
for(id item in HUDLayer._children)
```

should be fine.

Comment: I know it had to be something simple like that.  However, now it is saying the object 'HUDLayer' does not have a property children_

Comment: @Joey Not my fault - refer to the documentation of `HUDLayer`.

Comment: children_ is a property of CCNode, and is not declared in HUDLayer.  Is there a reason it would not recognize this property from CCNode?

Comment: @Joey Is `HUDLayer` an instance of `CCNode`?

Comment: No, it is a CCLayer, but CCLayer is a subclass of CCNode

Comment: @Joey Then it should be fine. Are you sure that property is called `children_` and not simply `children`?

Answer (score 0):

Just landed on this after doing a bit of Googling for another problem.

You're trying to remove objects from a parent, (HUDLayer). Someone else has answered with the issue with "self". However...

You said...

```
for(id *item in HUDLayer.children_) {
    [self removeChild:item cleanup:YES];
}
```

... but I though I'd add the code below as I thought it might help someone else trying to remove child nodes without getting a loop mutation.

```
for(id item in HUDLayer.children) {
    // If it's a sprite that you want to remove
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]]) {
        // Use this to remove or else you'll have a loop mutation.
        [item removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}
```

Anyhow, hope it helps someone.

Lol - editing this now, as I (reckon) iterating through and removing from, EVEN, the parent might cause an array mutation. So, I'm revising the above to first place all child elements in an array and I'm then iterating through IN REVERSE and removing objects on that basis. This way, the array mutation is avoided. See below:

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: HUDLayer.children];

for (long i = items.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    id item = items[i];
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]] ||
        [item removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }
}

items = nil;
```

Again - hope it helps someone.